Flyway migration Gradle task doesn't work
I have Kotlin Spring boot app, which using flyway migrations as gradle plugin. The need to use flyway migration as gradle app is to use JOOQ generation plugin (as a gradle task as well).
This is my build.gradle.kts, where i'm trying to get environment URL of db:
import nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqEdition
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.ForcedType
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Logging
import org.jooq.meta.jaxb.Property

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.25"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.25"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
    id("nu.studer.jooq") version "9.0"
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "10.21.0"
}

group = "com.robsil"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val jooqVersion = "3.19.15"

dependencies {
//  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq:$jooqVersion")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq-codegen:$jooqVersion")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq-codegen-gradle:$jooqVersion")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq-meta:$jooqVersion")
//  implementation("org.jooq.jooq-codegen-gradle:org.jooq.jooq-codegen-gradle.gradle.plugin:3.19.15")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-database-postgresql")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    jooqGenerator("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit5")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.1")
        classpath("org.flywaydb:flyway-database-postgresql:10.4.1")
    }
}

kotlin {
    compilerOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs.addAll("-Xjsr305=strict")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

val dbUrl: String = System.getenv("SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL") ?: "asd"
val dbUser: String = System.getenv("SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME") ?: "postgres"
val dbPassword: String = System.getenv("SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD") ?: "root"

flyway {
    url = dbUrl
    user = dbUser
    password = dbPassword
}

// https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin
jooq {
    version.set(jooqVersion)  // default (can be omitted)
    edition.set(JooqEdition.OSS)  // default (can be omitted)

    configurations {
        create("main") {  // name of the jOOQ configuration
            generateSchemaSourceOnCompilation.set(true)  // default (can be omitted)

            jooqConfiguration.apply {
                logging = Logging.WARN
                jdbc.apply {
                    driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
                    url = dbUrl
                    user = dbUser
                    password = dbPassword
                    properties.add(Property().apply {
                        key = "ssl"
                        value = "false"
                    })
                }
                generator.apply {
                    name = "org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGenerator"
                    database.apply {
                        name = "org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase"
                        inputSchema = "public"
                        forcedTypes.addAll(listOf(
                            ForcedType().apply {
                                name = "varchar"
                                includeExpression = ".*"
                                includeTypes = "JSONB?"
                            },
                            ForcedType().apply {
                                name = "varchar"
                                includeExpression = ".*"
                                includeTypes = "INET"
                            }
                        ))
                    }
                    generate.apply {
                        isDeprecated = false
                        isRecords = true
                        isImmutablePojos = true
                        isFluentSetters = true
                    }
                    target.apply {
                        packageName = "com.robsil.jooq"
                        directory = "build/generated-src/jooq/main"  // default (can be omitted)
                    }
                    strategy.name = "org.jooq.codegen.DefaultGeneratorStrategy"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.named<nu.studer.gradle.jooq.JooqGenerate>("generateJooq").configure {
    // ensure database schema has been prepared by Flyway before generating the jOOQ sources
    dependsOn(tasks.named("flywayMigrate"))

    // declare Flyway migration scripts as inputs on the jOOQ task
    inputs.files(fileTree("src/main/resources/db/migration"))
        .withPropertyName("migrations")
        .withPathSensitivity(PathSensitivity.RELATIVE)

    // make jOOQ task participate in incremental builds (and build caching)
    allInputsDeclared.set(true)
}

this is my docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    image: back
    build:
      context: back
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "7080:7080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=7080
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/lpnuqueue
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root

  postgres:
    image: postgres:16.4-alpine3.20
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./infrastructure/init_db.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init_db.sql
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", "--quiet" ]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10

volumes:
  db-data:

I'm even starting postgres manually firstly, and initializing database:
docker compose up postgres -d
and using intellij's db connect creating database
create database lpnuqueue;
then I'm trying to just build backend, which have this Dockerfile:
FROM gradle:jdk21-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app
RUN gradle clean build -x test

FROM amazoncorretto:22-alpine-jdk
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/build/libs/*.jar /app/*.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/*.jar"]

docker compose build backend
result:
PS C:\Users\robsil\IdeaProjects\lpnu_queue> docker compose build backend --no-cache

[+] Building 103.7s (11/12)                                                                                                                                          docker:default

=> [backend internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                      0.0s

=> => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                0.0s

=> [backend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                   0.0s

=> => transferring dockerfile: 298B                                                                                                                                           0.0s

=> [backend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:22-alpine-jdk                                                                                        1.0s

=> [backend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/gradle:jdk21-alpine                                                                                                 1.0s

=> [backend builder 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/gradle:jdk21-alpine@sha256:6791f33c09d827344e9ce914a3204812ec5259f0e0358826347c6d8928809310                                   0.0s

=> [backend stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:22-alpine-jdk@sha256:d36f9da84f78b4d933284ed516423ddfcec6c3e8ce1d3db800f715942a0968cb                          0.0s

=> [backend internal] load build context                                                                                                                                      0.0s

=> => transferring context: 24.10kB                                                                                                                                           0.0s

=> CACHED [backend stage-1 2/3] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                  0.0s

=> CACHED [backend builder 2/4] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                  0.0s

=> [backend builder 3/4] COPY . /app                                                                                                                                          0.1s

=> ERROR [backend builder 4/4] RUN gradle clean build -x test                                                                                                               102.4s

------

> [backend builder 4/4] RUN gradle clean build -x test:

1.429 Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

90.23 > Task :clean

90.23 > Task :checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors

101.3 > Task :flywayMigrate FAILED

101.4 [Incubating] Problems report is available at: file:///app/build/reports/problems/problems-report.html

101.4

101.4 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

101.4

101.4 * What went wrong:

101.4 Execution failed for task ':flywayMigrate'.

101.4 > Error occurred while executing flywayMigrate

101.4   No database found to handle asd

101.4

101.4 * Try:

101.4 > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.

101.4 > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

101.4 > Run with --scan to get full insights.

101.4 > Get more help at ``https://help.gradle.org``.

101.4

101.4 Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

101.4

101.4 You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

101.4

101.4 For more on this, please refer to ``https://docs.gradle.org/8.11/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings`` in the Gradle documentation.

101.4

101.4 BUILD FAILED in 1m 41s

101.4 3 actionable tasks: 3 executed

------

failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c gradle clean build -x test" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

postgres db is alive
Is there a solution to this problem, that my build.gradle.kts will use environment of docker compose container?
I actually tried this dockerfile:
FROM gradle:jdk21-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app

ENV SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/lpnuqueue
ENV SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
ENV SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root

COPY . /app
RUN gradle clean build -x test

FROM amazoncorretto:22-alpine-jdk
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/build/libs/*.jar /app/*.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT \["java", "-jar", "/app/\*.jar"\]

but it doesn't worked:
Execution failed for task ':flywayMigrate'.
120.0 \> Error occurred while executing flywayMigrate
120.0   Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/lpnuqueue) for user 'postgres': The connection attempt failed.
120.0   -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
120.0   SQL State  : 08001
120.0   Error Code : 0
120.0   Message    : The connection attempt failed.
120.0
120.0   The connection attempt failed.
120.0   postgres

as well as setting url to jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/lpnuqueue:
Execution failed for task ':flywayMigrate'.
115.2 \> Error occurred while executing flywayMigrate
115.2   Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/lpnuqueue) for user 'postgres': Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
115.2   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
115.2   SQL State  : 08001
115.2   Error Code : 0
115.2   Message    : Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
115.2
115.2   Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
115.2   Connection refused
115.2


A note of advice. I see that your environment is for local, though I would strongly recommend that you NEVER EVER publish in a public forum the password you are using for something you are running. Also make sure your local environment is only accessible from your local network. There are tons of bots running scanning open ports, so if for some reason your environment is in a public network it would fall victim of such attacks in no time. And even if it is a local environment use a non standard password.
